# Generate a random set from a limited set of chars in JavaScript using Math.random

Tags: javascript, math, random

I need to generate ~6 random characters using letters A-G and numbers 5-9. Can this be done using `Math.random`? They don't have to be unique every time. I have found this:

`Math.floor(0|Math.random()*9e6).toString(36)`

and it does work really well, but can I modify this to make it use certain characters (something like `replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '')` but in a more specific way) without adding `arrays` etc?

Edit: where is the fifth guy's answer?

Comment: is this for an exercise? or do you just want a solution to generate 6 random characters a-g and 5-9?

Comment: I think she wants to make an id or something @QiongWu

Comment: Yes, it is specifically for an ID generation like @TheOneWhoMade rightly said :) Sadly, the possibilities are really limited, can't use libraries...

Comment: @Mike McCaughan I have explored this and it was very helpful but due to limitations I can't use suggested solutions.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle see my answer @DarienneLake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use different function with different factors and offsets for letters and numbers in the wanted range.

```js
function getRandomLetter() { // A B C D E F G
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase();
    //                                ^       count of wanted letters
    //                                    ^^  offset for the first letter, to get A
    //                                        with a random result of zero
}

function getRandomNumber() { // 5 6 7 8 9
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 5).toString(36);
    //                                ^      9 - 5 + 1 or count, as factor
    //                                    ^  offset 
}
    
console.log(getRandomLetter());
console.log(getRandomNumber());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can totally use Math to pick random elements from the array (in this case the characters that will construct the random Id code) and concatenate those into the code string

steps:

- first make an array with the "building" blocks of the code string.
- then make an empty string to hold the codes string.
- run a loop (number of times depends on how long you want the code to be)
- **Math Part:** you need a random index. To do so you generate a random number using Math.random() which will give you something between 0-1. Then you multiply it by the length of the building blocks array, so that the result will be somewhere between 0 - array.length. Then you wrap this in Math.Floor to make sure you get a clean integer out of this process which will be your random index.
- Then you simply add the random character to the codeString by picking array[randomIndex] and concatenating it to the codeString.
- the loop will repeat istself and in the end you will have your codeString.

Code:

```
const array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
let codeString = "";

for(i=0 ; i<6 ; i++){
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()* array.length);
    codeString = codeString + array[randomIndex];
}
console.log(codeString);
```

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade I feel like you're being quite harsh with the critique of my answer. In the end if offered a working 6 lines of code solution to a problem, as well as an attempt to explain it thoroughly step by step. Putting my specific answer aside, do you think answers here should be complete fit-in to the asker's code? I personally think that explaining a core principal that the user can understand and apply in his/hers own coding is better. But this is completely open for debate of course. In this scenario the question is rather open in the notion that it does ask for a general approach.

Comment: My mind is numb. And you had 3 characters left. I am in awe. @CodeAt30

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of the random characters appearing isn't very important then I would do something like this

```
// This function helps us generate a random number between two numbers. 
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// The characters we need
var characterArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// Now run a loop six times, get a random number between 0 and the length of the characterArray and concatenate it into a new variable

var randomString = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    randomString += characterArray[ random(0, characterArray.length - 1) ];
}

console.log( randomString );
```

The code can be shortened even further for e.g instead of actually making an array of characters, we can assign a string `characterArray = "ABCDE...7,8,9"` as a string is also an array of characters and serves the purpose similarly, but I thought it would be a good idea to write it in a way that is self-explanatory for you to understand and add or change anything in the code as you like.

With a function to give us a random number between two numbers, we can use an array that contains all the characters that our result can have. Then, since we want to get a random number with 6 different characters we use a `for loop`, run it six times, each time it gets a random element from the array of characters, and does the job.